# How to iterate through an array in a sequence using forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, sequence, marklogic, marklogic-9

I am using the xdmp.eval function to search and return a document in my final database to use during my harmonization process.

```
let finalDoc = xdmp.eval(
"fn.head(cts.search(cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery('Id',id, 
['exact']),['unfiltered','score-zero']))",
     {'id':id},
     {"database" : xdmp.database("data-hub-FINAL")});
```

The document is returned as a sequence with this structure:

```
{"SourceSystemName":"",
  "BatchDtTm":"06/20/2018 15:05:15",
  "SubjectArea":"Customer",
  "DocumentType":"Registration",
   "Id":"100", 
     "Contact":[
       {"CustomerId":"1",
        "FirstName":"",
        "LastName":"",
        "EmailId":""
       },
       {"CustomerId":"2",
        "FirstName":"",
        "LastName":"",
        "EmailId":""
       }            
     ]
}
```

I need to iterate through each customer in the **Contact** array using **finalDoc.Contact.forEach()**. However, when I use fn.head(finalDoc.toArray()) or fn.head(finalDoc.toObject()) to change the finalDoc sequence to an array, my forEach function fails with the error **"Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"**. When I simply just try to output the contact array by doing finalDoc.Contact (or finalDoc[0].Contact), I get a "Null" output.

How do I grab the Contact array out of the sequence and iterate through it using forEach? Thanks!

Comment: `finalDoc = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(finalDoc));` try this.

Comment: what is the problem with assigning it? `var arr = yourObj.Contact`

Answer (score 3):

You have the right pieces, just the wrong order. `fn.head` doesn't take an array, so it has no effect in `fn.head(finalDoc.toArray())`: you'll still have an array. You could convert the sequence to an array and then use the array index:

```
finalDoc.toArray()[0].Contact.forEach(...)
```

or you can use the `fn.head` on the originally eval'd Sequence

```
fn.head(finalDoc).Contact.forEach(...)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I used your first suggestion and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

```js
var myobj = {"SourceSystemName":"",
  "BatchDtTm":"06/20/2018 15:05:15",
  "SubjectArea":"Customer",
  "DocumentType":"Registration",
   "Id":"100", 
     "Contact":[
       {"CustomerId":"1",
        "FirstName":"",
        "LastName":"",
        "EmailId":""
       },
       {"CustomerId":"2",
        "FirstName":"",
        "LastName":"",
        "EmailId":""
       }            
     ]
}

myobj["Contact"].forEach(function(item){
console.log(item);
})
```

I think you don't need to call toArray() if it is an object already.